# How do I remove Bootstrap classes from vscode Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I had previously used bootstrap for one of my projects in vscode.
Vscode keeps showing the bootstrap classes in intellisense autocomplete even though I didn't use bootstrap in subsequent projects. It causes my code to be written with the bootstrap classes unintentionally.

How do I remove the bootstrap classes from intellisense? Or have it only be used when I link in the bootstrap stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this extension `IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML` because it shows the CSS classes in HTML and that might be your problem?

if not check your extensions maybe one of them is doing the same job and it is showing the classes. and that only happens when you have the Bootstrap files in your project as far as I know.

If the problem still occurs make sure you add a brand new folder to the vscode. Then start building your project files and see if the problem occurs again or not.

Comment: Thanks! It was HTML Css Support extension.